# OS X: How to make dictionary with weak refs to objects on 10.7, ARC enabled

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary, weak-references

How can one create a dictionary of objects with **weak references** -- that is, the dictionary does not retain its keys and values -- on OS X 10.7 with ARC enabled? NSMapTable looks promising but unfortunately it doesn't use weak references when ARC is enabled.

Comment: Your question title says OS X 10.8.  Your question text says OS X 10.7.  Which version did you mean?

Comment: It doesn't really matter does it? i mean use `NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory` pre 10.8 and `NSMapTableWeakMemory` for 10.8+

Comment: @robmayoff thanks, my mistake. The question refers to 10.7 and I have corrected the title. On 10.8+ +[NSMapTable weakToWeakObjectsMapTable] suffices like Brad mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMapTable is indeed what you want.

### 10.8+:

specifically in your case it sounds like you want to use this:

> ```
> + (id)weakToWeakObjectsMapTable
> Return Value
> A new map table object which has weak references to the keys and values.
> ```

from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html):

> The major option is to have keys and/or values held “weakly” in a manner that entries are removed when one of the objects is reclaimed.

you can use either the shortcut class methods `+ (id)weakToWeakObjectsMapTable` or `+ (id)weakToStrongObjectsMapTable` depending on your needs.

also see `NSMapTableOptions` to see how to specify behavior to the other initializers.

> NSMapTableWeakMemory
>   Uses weak read and write barriers appropriate for **ARC** or GC. Using NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory object references will turn to NULL on last release. Equal to NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory.

### 10.7+:

use `– initWithKeyOptions:valueOptions:capacity:` and pass `NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory` in the options (assuming your objects are "weak-reference-safe")
alternatively you can use `– initWithKeyPointerFunctions:valuePointerFunctions:capacity:` and specify custom functions if none of the built in ones work for you / arent available on you version. (maybe one of the "opaque" personalities would work for you)

Comment: Hi Brad, are you sure that on 10.7 the `NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory` option does in fact use weak refs with ARC? `NSMapTableWeakMemory` definitely does, but that's only available on 10.8. IMHO the docs aren't really clear on whether `NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory` uses weak refs that zero out, uses weak refs that don't zero out, or doesn't support weak refs at all.

Comment: I don't know about your specific case but the docs for `NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory` say "objects must be weak-reference-safe under manual and automatic reference counting; not all objects are." so I guess that depends on what objects you are working with. you could always use `- (id)initWithKeyPointerFunctions:valuePointerFunctions:capacity:` instead.

Comment: NSMapTableZeroingWeakMemory is weak under GC only